# Mollified random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, smooth-functions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given a random variable $X$ with cdf that is not smooth, I read that we can construct a random variable denoted as $X\cdot M$ with smooth cdf and smooth inverse cdf, where $M$ is a random variable supported in $[0,1]$ having smooth cdf. The reference refers to this as a standard mollifier argument and does not provide further details. My question is how this construction works. Is the $\cdot$ merely a product or denotes something else? How does one show the claim? Thank you for any suggestions or reference provided.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier and references, as well as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/572557/how-to-sample-and-compute-the-likelihood-from-a-mollified-uniform-distribution and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332485/is-there-a-continuous-version-of-the-uniform-distribution

Comment: I have read the references, could it be that $X\cdot M$ is not the product, but actually denotes the random variable $X+M$, so that it is the random variable having as density the convolution of the densities? I wonder why using the product notation then...